# Excepción al asignar variable de session C# sobre método [ActionName()]

Tags: c#

Se genera una excepción al intentar declarar una variable de sesión sobre el siguiente método

```
   public class LoginController : ApiController
   {
     [HttpPost]
     [ActionName("Login")]
     public void Login(Usuarios usuario)
     {

        //Por no depender LoginController de Controller, no se reconoce
        //Session["Usuario"] = "Vegeta";

        //De esta forma si se reconoce como tal la variable de tipo session, pero genera el error descrito
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Usuario", "Vegeta");
     }
   }
```

Detalle de la excepción

**+       $exception  {"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."} System.NullReferenceException**

**Dato:** Estoy invocando ese metodo desde javaScript por medio de WebApi

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El uso de WebApi implica autenticación por medio de tokens que va en los headers de las peticiones (requests). El uso de sesiones va mucho mejor en un ambiente de ASP.net WebForms, MVC

Comment: Si ok.. ese es todo el error que te sale?? no sale nada mas??? evidentemente session es nulo...

Comment: si es todo amigo

Comment: un comentario útil @fredyfx gracias investigare sobre ello

Comment: de nada :D revisa la documentación oficial: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security Por cierto, si estás usando ASP.net Core, la situación cambia: https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core